# Apache 2 - I have webmin running on port 10000...I want it to be accessed the normal HTTP port (80)

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, port, configuration

Currently I am doing this with the config.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName testsite.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@testsite.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature on

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName panel.testsite.org
        ProxyPass / http://panel.testsite.org:10000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://panel.testsite.org:10000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, but now I need to use a Perl CGI on the panel.testsite.org to find the REMOTE_ADDR and its displaying the server's IP...because of this proxy workaround. What is a better way I can perform what I need without using a proxy or anything that will mess up REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: This is a server configuration issue. Voting to send it over to SF.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using a proxy, you should be using the [Reverse Proxy Request Headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers):

- `X-Forwarded-For`
  The IP address of the client.
- `X-Forwarded-Host`
  The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
- `X-Forwarded-Server`
  The hostname of the proxy server.